# EF6 first query memory usage

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6.1.3 with a fairly large database structure (177 tables, 1673 columns).  When I run my first query, according to memory profiling, EF is allocating 225MB.  This seems a pretty heavy memory load.

I've been getting out of memory exceptions and whilst this isn't likely to be the main culprit, I am conscious that it is probably contributing to it.

Does this sound like typical memory usage?  Is there any way of reducing it short of reducing the complexity of the structure?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Visual Studio's memory profiler was misreporting as I've been monitoring it via task manager and it uses <50MB for the whole app to get to that point.